# Pass file content to docker exec

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command, arguments

I am learning with docker containers and I'd like to pass .sql file to database using docker exec.
How can I do that?
I am searching for about an hour now and found this:

```
cat file.sql | docker exec -it mariadb sh -c 'mysql -u<user> -p<pass>'
```

or this

```
docker exec -it mariadb sh -c 'mysql -u<user> -p<pass> "$(< /path/file.sql)"'
```

but neither of it worked. I think there is problem that I am passing it into sh -c and it tries to load that file from inside the container. How can I do it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

there's more than one way to do it, of course; most of your invocations are close, but if you execute docker with `-t` it will allocate a terminal for i/o and that will interfere with stream opearations.

My recent invocation from shell history was :

```
docker exec -i mysql mysql -t  < t.sql
```

in my case of course `mysql` is the running container name.  You'll note that I do *not* pass `-t` to the `docker exec` - I do however pass it to `mysql` command line program that I exec on the docker host, so don't get confused there.

The shell that interprets that command and executes docker is also the one that opens `t.sql` and redirects that file descriptor to `docker`'s stdin, so `t.sql` here is in the current working directory of the host shell, not the container shell.

That having been said, here's why yours didn't work.  In the first place, as I said, the use of `exec -it` allocates a terminal that interferes with the stdin stream that the bash shell set up from `cat`.  In the second place, you're really close, but path/file.sql wasn't on the docker image so I'm guessing that threw a 'no such file or directory' because `file.sql` is on the host, not the container, yet it's referenced within the `-c` parameter to the container's `sh` execution.  Of course, that would also need `-t` to be removed; in neither case does a terminal need to be allocated (you already have one, and it will already be the stdout for the docker execution as it will inherit the shell's un-redirected stdout).

Comment: Hi Dan, is it possible to have "both" file redirection and terminal works? Let's say if the database needs to use a password to login and we don't want to input the password in command line interface like `docker exec -i something mysql -u root -proot`, but use `docker exec -it something mysql -u root -p` and then input the password. After that use the file input `< t.sql`. Generally is like "Delay the redirect after we make some interaction", is it possible? Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: I don't know of such a way to change the input stream for a running process from a terminal to a file.  I suggest you might put a mysql password in ~/.my.cnf, which for you would be /root/.my.cnf.

Comment: I know this was several years ago, but when I try this the script runs but does not exit the docker command. You need to CTRL+C to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend you ask in a new question so you can show the exact command you're running and the behavior you describe.